# Dynamic items in Drawer nested in Stack Navigator react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i`m realy stumped about this.
I have a bottom tabs width 4 screens

**BottomTabs.js**

```
export const AllTabs = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" tabBar={props => <BottomNavigation {...props} />}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} options={{
            icon: 'shopping-store'
        }}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Catalog" component={CatalogStack} options={{
            icon: 'pulse'
        }}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Cart" component={CartStack} options={{
            icon: 'shopping-basket'
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStack} options={{
            icon: 'person'
        }}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

In first Screen named Home, in **HomeStack**:

```
export const HomeStack = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions} >
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="SectionDrawer" component={SectionDrawer} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

I calling drawer component in second screen

**Drawer**

```
export const SectionDrawer = (props) => {
    const { route, navigation } = props
    const { list } = route.params
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContentOptions={{ activeBackgroundColor: '#5cbbff', activeTintColor: '#ffffff' }} >
            <Drawer.Screen name="Section" component={SectionScreen} options={{ route, navigation }}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}
```

And finally in SectionScreen i`m fetcing data with api by id

**SectionScreen**

```
export const SectionScreen = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const {route, navigation} = props
    const { sectionID } = route.params

    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('url, {
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setProductList(json))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);

    return (
        <Content padder>
            <Text>section screen.</Text>
            <Text>Requested id {sectionID}</Text>
            {isLoading ? (
                <Spinner />
            ) : (
                <ProductCards list={productList} perLine={2} navigation={navigation}/>
            )}
        </Content>
    )
}
```

I calling SectionScreen in drawer with this construction:

```
<CardItem cardBody button onPress={() => {
  navigation.dispatch(
     CommonActions.navigate({
        name: 'SectionDrawer',
        params: {
           screen: 'SectionScreen',
           params: {
              title: card.title,
              sectionID: card.id
           }
         },
      })
    );
}}>
```

All of this works ... but I need to push in drawer dynamic links fetched from api
I am tried: in Drawer

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerContentOptions={{ activeBackgroundColor: '#5cbbff', activeTintColor: '#ffffff' }} >
   {list.map((item, index) => <Drawer.Screen name={item.title} component={SectionScreen}  key={index}/>)}         
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

and in place where I calling SectionScreen:

```
<CardItem cardBody button onPress={() => {
    navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.navigate({
            name: 'SectionDrawer',
            params: {
                list,
                screen: card.title,
                params: {
                    title: card.title,
                    sectionID: card.id
                }
            },
        })
    );
}}>
```

After this I see items that I passed in list param,
but when i try to navigate to them, i have error in SectionScreen route.param.id is not defined, and route.params is undefined too.

Also i trying to fetch data that I need in drawer, in drawer component, and draw it with

`drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}`

and render them with:
`{catalogSections.map((item, index) => <DrawerItem label={item.title} focused onPress={() => drawerNavigate(navigation, item)} key={index}/>)}`
and it works fine but i cannot select active item from them...

help me please how right to add items to drawer and navigate always to one component with different params